# Will a bubble with an acceleration of $a$ in a soda bottle remain stationary when the bottle is dropped under gravity?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, fluid-statics

A bubble moves with an accelation"a" inside a bottle of soda. When the bottle is dropped freely will the bubble remain stationary?

[image]

Comment: This is not a **do my homework** site . Demands for **someone else** to do your homework for you (for free) is  probably is not the best way to get help. But if you write out, in your post, what you think or have attempted,  that might get you a hint.   [Homework Policy](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/714/how-do-i-ask-homework-questions-on-physics-stack-exchange)

Comment: I have got the answer... But I don't know how this works out... Having some confusions with effective gravity?

Comment: Write out what you do know and a diagram. The answer is not as important as knowing how to do it, we both know that. Write out the steps you would take to solve it.

Comment: My doubt on this question is why should the bubble remain stationary since there will be a resultant acceleration to the upward direction? Since the bottle falls down under gravity the bubble feels weightlessness but why doesn't the force due to "a" come into play? Hope I would get an answer...

Comment: Answers $(3)$ and $(5)$ are the same? It's obviously not either of them anyway. The acceleration is in opposite directions - One due to gravity and the other is the acceleration of the bubble - So it's not additive and hence cannot be $(2)$. Just leaves $(1)$ and $(4)$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Imagine that you are in a lift holding a metal sphere.
Suddenly the cable breaks and the lift, the metal sphere, the air and you are in free fall accelerating at the same rate.
You let go of the sphere.
Describe the subsequent motion of the metal sphere.

Imagine that you are in a lift full of water holding a spherical air bubble.
Yet again the cable breaks and the lift, the bubble of air, the water and you are in free fall accelerating at the same rate.
You let go of the air bubble.
Describe the subsequent motion of the air bubble.

Comment: In these types of motions we would experience "weightlessness" since the sphere or bubble is falling under gravity. But what confuses me here is the acceleration "a"of the bubble to the upward direction... Won't it have any effect on the motion?

Comment: The acceleration $a$ was due to the upthrust on the gas bubble. The upthrust was there because of the change in pressure with depth in a liquid. Does a pressure gradient exist in the situations mentioned above?

Comment: Thanks dude I got it... There won't be any pressure gradient in these types of scenarios...